# PHP and MySQL Login Page HTTP Error 500

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am creating a PHP and MySQL login page. I have got registration to work but when I got to the login page I get an HTTP 500 Error. I'm pretty sure it's the login.php file because the registration works which is using the same connect.php file.

login.php

```
<?php  //Start the Session
session_start();
require('../inc/connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }else{
        $fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "Hai " . $username . "";
    echo "This is the Members Area";
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

}else{
    echo  "Please login.";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Login Using PHP & MySQL</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
  <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Login</h2>
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
</div>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" href="register.php">Register</a>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'beta');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

Comment: 500 Errors are catastrophic errors. It usually means the PHP is generating a huge error. Did this script ever work? If so what was your last change?

Comment: NOTE: Parameter 4 of a `mysqli_connect()` can be used for a database name. You can then get rid of the `mysqli_select_db()` completely

Comment: @RiggsFolly The script has not worked before.

Comment: Then what were you last code amendments. That is where the error will be

Comment: Have to looked at the error log?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, I forgot about logs, fixed the problem now!

Comment: you're not live or intending to go live with this, are you?

Answer (score 0):

the reason it wasn't working is it says "../inc/connect.php" which pulls from another directory, not the web root. So I changed it to "./inc/connect.php" which works.